# The best practice of distribution data across all Angular Universal components?

Tags: angular, rxjs, data-sharing

I have got a pretty big Angular SPA with router-outlets and different level components.
Currently, my application supports different regions where each region is a separate routing with relevant data attached:

```
{
    path: 'Saint-Petersburg', canActivate: [MetaGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./components/main-page/main-page.module').then(m => m.MainPageModule),
    data: { region: regions[1] }
 }
```

The change of a region is done via routing data and localstorage So, when a user changes a region, Angular app:
1) obtains region data from routing  (here `data: { region: regions[1] }` )
2) updates region value in the local storage
3) reloads the application (window.reload)
4) all components check region from localstorage and provide relevant data.

The solution works fine but error-prone because:
1) I need to always read a region from localstorage
2) Data provided in the routing can only be shared with the module specified in the routing
3) Local storage is not Angular Universal friendly

Could you advise the best solution for storing a region or accessing it across all components?
Do I need to use a Service with Subjects?
Or use RxJS similar to Redux?

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need to store a region state, you could use a singleton service for that

```
   @Injectable({
  providedIn:"root"
})
export class RegionStore{
    private _region$ = new BehaviourSubject<string>();

    public region$(){
      return this._region$.asObservable();
    }

    public region(){
      return this._region$.getValue();
    }

    changeRegion(region:string){
      this._region$.next(region);
    }

}
```

but if you want to have application state as a whole, then you could use [NGRX](https://ngrx.io/) [NGXS](https://www.ngxs.io/) [Akita](https://github.com/datorama/akita)

Comment: Thank you very much, Onik. Do you which library is the best NGRX or NGXS or Akita?
Or there is not much differences ?

Comment: Oh, it's a really big topic :P.  they all are great libraries, just choose one and stick with it.  if you are new to state management, AKITA and NGXS have an easier learning curve. so maybe start from one of them, and then move to NGRX. I prefer to use NGRX, but once again all they do the same thing, but with different perspective

Comment: Do you know if NGRX is Angular Universal (Server Side Rendering) friendly?

Comment: yes all of them are universal friendly